# how to get span value and add the value as class/id to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help, I need to get the value of the span eg. `<span itemprop="title">God Of War</span>` which is "God Of War" and assign the value as an ID or Class to a div. How can I do that in Javascript?

Comment: You can't do that. Some characters such as a space are not valid in id or class names.

Comment: Yup I just realized that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<span itemprop="title">God Of War</span>
<div>You will see result here</div>
<button>Do</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
   $('button').click(function(){
      $('div').attr('class', $('span[itemprop="title"]').html())
              .html('filled a class');
   });
});
```

Click the `button` -> Right click the `div` -> inspect element -> and you will see your div has been filled with class you want.

See here -> http://jsfiddle.net/aldiunanto/HdPWs/

Answer (score 0):

You tagged your post as jquery so I'm assuming jquery is acceptable.  Take a look at these functions in the jquery api for more details.

`$('div').attr('id', $('span[itemprop="title"]').html());`

Answer (score 0):

Frist you can assign a class or id to the span then
Use Javascript simple

```
document.getElementById('spanid / class').innerHTML;
```